# Error while posting form: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

i am sending 5 values from form which are name,email,password,confirm password and city but when this code executed i get the specified error

CODE:

```
    <%---<%@ page errorPage="addbookerror.jsp" %> --%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"  %>
 <%@ page import="bean.*" %>
<%@ page import="database.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:useBean id="d" class="database.studentDAO" scope="page"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:useBean id="s" class="bean.studentInfo" scope="page"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:setProperty name="s" property="name" param="st_name"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="s" property="email" param="st_email"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="s" property="pwd" param="st_password"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="s" property="cpwd" param="st_confirm_password"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="s" property="city" param="st_city"/>
<%
d.addStudent(s);

%>

</body>
</html>
```

ERROR:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /Admin/add_st_ac.jsp at line 20

17: <jsp:setProperty name="s" property="cpwd" param="st_confirm_password"/>
18: <jsp:setProperty name="s" property="city" param="st_city"/>
19: <%
20: d.addStudent(s);
21: 
22: %>
23:
```

Comment: What does addStudent(s) do?

Comment: add student information to database

Comment: OK. could you add the code for this function?

Comment: you want the database code or the form code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the schema of the student database (database code) you are using as well as the actual `addStudent` definition?

It is likely that you manually tried to build the query in your `addStudent` function, but was not able to fill all the columns required.